# MS Access Lock a record based on Combo Box?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to figure out how to lock a record once I have it set to "Completed" status using a combo box. I have it using a timestamp in a [Date Completed] field and I want to lock it so that field can't be changed again once it has been set. 
Without this or something like it in place you can keep selecting "In progress" or "Completed" and continually update the time and I'm trying to stop that from happening.

I've tried the following but it locks all the records.

```
Private Sub Staus_BeforeChange(Cancel As Integer)
'Private Sub Status_Change()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim ValueList()


'In progress
If [Status] = 10 Then
[StartDate] = Now()

'Completed
ElseIf [Status] = 100 Then
   [DateCompleted] = Now()

     'Lock record if completed status
        'If Form.CurrentRecord.[Status] = 100 Then
        'Form.CurrentRecord.AllowEdits = False
        'Else
        'Form.CurrentRecord.AllowEdits = True
        'End If

'Transferred
ElseIf [Status] = -10 Then
   [DateTransferred] = Now()
   'Copy Record without completed date
    DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acEditMenu, 8, , acMenuVer70
    DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acEditMenu, 2, , acMenuVer70
    DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acEditMenu, 5, , acMenuVer70
    [Status] = 0
    [StartDate] = Null
    [User ID] = "Unassigned"
    [DateTransferred] = Null
    [DueDate] = [DueDate]
MsgBox "The following Task has been transferred:" & " " & Me.[Company] & " " & Me.[Task Name]

'Waiting
ElseIf [Status] = 50 Then
   [DateCompleted] = Now()
End If

Forms![frmTasks].Form.Requery
Forms![frmTasks].Form.Refresh

End Sub


Public beforeValueChange As Integer

beforeValueChange = Me.[Status]

End Sub


Private Sub Status_AfterUpdate()

If Not IsNull(Me.[DateCompleted]) Then

Me.[Status] = beforeValueChange

End If

End Sub
```

I appreciate any help or push in the right direction.
Thanks!!!
-Deke

Comment: You need to use the `Form.Current` event to achieve this.  This runs each time you load a new record (by moving through the data set).  You can then see what values are available in the current record and set the form appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that isn't preventing the user from making changes then maybe the below?

```
Public beforeValueChange As Int


Private Sub Staus_BeforeChange(Cancel As Integer)

beforeValueChange = Me.[Status]

End Sub


Private Sub Status_AfterUpdate()

If Not IsNull(Me.[DateCompleted]) Then

    Me.[Status] = beforeValueChange

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I think your `Public Dim beforeValueChange As String` is in error there is no end Function or Sub.

Comment: @Deke My apologies. Removed the Dim, not needed when defined outside a Function or Sub

Comment: Thanks! I keep getting an error "Field 'tblTasks.Status' cannot be a zero-length string". Any idea why it's pulling that? The status is currently set to "In Progress" which isn't a zero string.

Comment: Sounds like a datatype issue? Looks like your status is an int. Does the edited question fix that? Look again.

Comment: Nope still getting the same issue.

Comment: Can you paste your code in the question with an edit? Need to see the context

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193845/discussion-between-chance-finley-and-deke).